# Notation problem in Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Consider two sets : 
$\{1,2,3\}$ and $\{1,2,3,4\}$

What is $\{1,2,3\}\setminus\{1,2,3,4\}$?

I am giving an example of the two sets. I want to understand what that $\setminus$
of the two sets above imply?

Comment: {1,2,3}\{1,2,3,4}

Comment: It means the set of elements in the first set, but not the second, so $\emptyset$ in your example.

Answer (score 1):

$A\setminus B$ is the set containing all elements of $A$ not in $B$. It is a subset of $A$.

Here, as $A\subseteq B$, $A\setminus B=\varnothing$.